# twitteR package function getFollowers() not working for all users

Tags: r, twitter

Hello I have the following code and don't understand the error. I can find the user arconic and pull tweets from the account, but I don't know why I can't find the followers. Any ideas?

```
setup_twitter_oauth(consumer_key,
                consumer_secret,
                access_token,
                access_secret)

> getUser("@brent_ferrier")
[1] "brent_ferrier"
> getUser("@arconic")
[1] "arconic"
> getUser("@brent_ferrier")$getFollowers(retryOnRateLimit=180)
$`80172448`
[1] "givesuponlove"
$`256679525`
[1] "katiewebster30"

> getUser("@arconic")$getFollowers(retryOnRateLimit=180)
Error in twInterfaceObj$doAPICall(paste("users", "show", sep = "/"), params = params,  : 
client error: (404) Not Found
> tweets<-userTimeline("arconic",n=3200)
> length(tweets)
[1] 159
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

twitteR is deprecated in favor of rtweet. So I can tell you what would work with rtweet:

```
## v0.4.0 published on CRAN today
install.packages("rtweet")

## load pkg
library(rtweet)

## if your token is already saved as .httr-oauth then
## it should work or you can checkout
#?create_token 

## Even better save token as envir var instructions here:
#vignettes("auth", "rtweet")

## there's actually a built-in token in rtweet as well but 
## it won't be as reliable as your own token. it's mostly
## there to let people test drive the pkg.

## to get followers for a user
flw <- get_followers("brent_ferrier")

## the same basic way to get friends 
fds <- get_friends("brent_ferrier")

## lookup users data for both followers and friends
usrs <- lookup_users(c(flw$user_id, fds$user_id))

## or timeline of a user's tweets
bf <- get_timeline("brent_ferrier", n = 3200)

## create a neat time series plot of tweets
ts_filter(bf, "days") %>% 
    ts_plot(lwd = 2, theme = "spacegray",
            main = "Tweets from brent_ferrier",
            subtitle = "Collected using rtweet")
```

You can also view package documentation on the rtweet package website as well: http://mkearney.github.io/rtweet

Comment: Thanks for the help! I was unaware of this package.